# Describe by set notation that a subset of events happen

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I struggle with finding an efficient way to notate the following tasks. From $n$ events $A_1, A_2, \dots, A_n$

1. exactly one event happens
2. exactly $n-1$ happens

There is a [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/512548/probability-exactly-one-of-a-and-b-occurs) on finding the notation for two events but not on the general case of $n$ (to the best of my knowledge).

If possible, please elaborate a bit on your solution. Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please review the [Meta Read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and enhance your question to provide your motivation/attempts.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have indicated a post that deals with a similar topic but does not answer the question at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\overline{A_k}$ be the complement of $A_k$, that is the event that $A_k$ does not happen.  To reduce the notational clutter, notate intersection by juxtaposition.  That is, $AB$ means $A\cap B$.  Then the probability that exactly one event happens is $$\bigcup_{k=1}^n\overline{A_1}\overline{A_2}\cdots\overline{A_{k-1}}A_k\overline{A_{k+1}}\cdots\overline{A_n}$$

The second case may be written similarly, by reversing the complemented and non-complemented symbols.

I don't know what kind of elaboration would be appropriate.  Please ask me if you have questions.

Comment: Thank you @saulspatz! Let me ask you a follow-up question on your answer. If $A_k$ is the event that happens while the others jointly do not happen, what is the role of the $\bigcup$? What do we need it for?